# Why my recoverable module from Devise gem isn't working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, password-recovery

I have UserMailer class with next code:

User.rb:

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  -----------------

 class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

 default :from => "denys.medynskyi@gmail.com"

 def password_reset(user, password)
   @user = user
   @password = password
  mail(:to => user.email,
     :subject => 'Password Reset Notification')
  end

  def congrats_email(user)
    mail(to: user.email, subject: "Welcome Message")
 end

 end
```

setup_mail.rb:

```
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :domain               => "gmail.com",
   :user_name            => "denys.medynskyi",
   :password             => "********",
   :authentication       => "plain",
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }
```

and from devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  config.mailer_sender = "UserMailer"
end
```

and after forgot password submit I go to some page, but it deosn't show me any notice adn doesn't send email.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is the cause of any or all of your problems, but if you're trying to work with `Devise`, overriding some of the default mailer behavior but not *all* of it, you should inherit from `Devise::Mailer` rather than `ActionMailer::Base`.

So

```
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
```

Edit: The method that `Devise` calls in `Devise::Mailer` to render the password reset mail template is `reset_password_instructions`. So your method isn't even overwriting that. Also, the way `Devise` works, it's the resource that eventually calls the method that sends the instructions e-mail. The job of the `reset_password_instructions` method is just to generate the e-mail from the view template. So it looks to me like the code you've got above isn't really working with the normal `Devise` flow. What calls `password_reset` in your app?

Comment: It should send email with instructions.